# How to set parameters for Realtek wifi rtl8723

Tags: 14.04, wireless, drivers, realtek

I have a realtek wifi card which is really messing up the internet connection on my laptop. As per a few launchpad bugs,they have suggested to disable msi and powersave. 
How do I set the parameters msi, swlps, ips and fwlps? details of the wifi card driver is below.

```
 modinfo rtl8723be
filename:       /lib/modules/3.16.3-031603-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtl8723be/rtl8723be.ko
firmware:       rtlwifi/rtl8723befw.bin
description:    Realtek 8723BE 802.11n PCI wireless
license:        GPL
author:         Realtek WlanFAE <wlanfae@realtek.com>
author:         PageHe  <page_he@realsil.com.cn>
srcversion:     8630CF9344D90D47240D1FF
alias:          pci:v000010ECd0000B723sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
depends:        rtlwifi,rtl_pci,btcoexist,mac80211
vermagic:       3.16.3-031603-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           swlps:bool
parm:           swenc:using hardware crypto (default 0 [hardware])
 (bool)
parm:           ips:using no link power save (default 1 is open)
 (bool)
parm:           fwlps:using linked fw control power save (default 1 is open)
 (bool)
parm:           msi:Set to 1 to use MSI interrupts mode (default 0)

parm:           debug:Set debug level (0-5) (default 0) (int)
parm:           disable_watchdog:Set to 1 to disable the watchdog (default 0)
 (bool)
```

Wireless card

```
lspci  | grep -i wire
 02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
```

if I set msi=0 i get the following error

```
[   18.096063] rtl8723be: unknown parameter 'msi' ignored
```

Comment: Could you post how you tried to set `msi=0`?

Comment: `cat /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf `
`options rtl8723be fwlps=0 swlps=0 ips=0`
`#options MSI=1`

Answer (score 3):

Before you start, you will need to install `sysfsutils`:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sysfsutils
```

First, to show the options that are currently in use and the existing parameters, run the following command:

```
sudo systool -a -v -m rtl8723be | grep -A8 "Parameters:"
```

Under "Parameters:", you will see the available options and the existing parameters. Here is an example of that section:

```
  Parameters:
    debug               = "1"
    disable_watchdog    = "N"
    fwlps               = "Y"
    ips                 = "Y"
    msi                 = "Y"
    swenc               = "N"
    swlps               = "N"
```

It appears that the msi option can be set to `Y` or `N`.

To set msi to off, you should run the following commands:

```
sudo modprobe -r rtl8723be
sudo modprobe rtl8723be msi=N
```

Now, verify the change:

```
sudo systool -a -v -m rtl8723be | grep -A8 "Parameters:"
```

The output should now look like this:

```
  Parameters:
    debug               = "1"
    disable_watchdog    = "N"
    fwlps               = "Y"
    ips                 = "Y"
    msi                 = "N"
    swenc               = "N"
    swlps               = "N"
```

To make this change permanent, you should create a file `/etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf`. Run the following command:

```
sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf
```

Now, copy and paste the following into the file:

```
options rtl8723be debug=1
options rtl8723be disable_watchdog=N
options rtl8723be fwlps=Y
options rtl8723be ips=Y
options rtl8723be msi=N
options rtl8723be swenc=N
options rtl8723be swlps=N
```

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>o</kbd> and then press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> to save the file. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> to exit nano.

Now you can make changes to this file to apply your desired settings. After you make changes to the file, run the following commands to apply the changes:

```
sudo modprobe -r rtl8723be
sudo modprobe rtl8723be
```

Comment: There is a new parameter in new versions "ant_sel" that is very useful for 1 antenna laptops.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 with 14.10 kernel. It does work for me.

```
~$ sudo modprobe  rtl8723be msi=0
~$ more /sys/module/rtl8723be/parameters/msi 
N
~$ sudo modprobe -r rtl8723be
~$ sudo modprobe  rtl8723be msi=1
~$ more /sys/module/rtl8723be/parameters/msi 
Y
```

Same module version:

```
~$ modinfo rtl8723be
filename:       /lib/modules/3.16.0-23-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtl8723be/rtl8723be.ko
firmware:       rtlwifi/rtl8723befw.bin
description:    Realtek 8723BE 802.11n PCI wireless
license:        GPL
author:         Realtek WlanFAE <wlanfae@realtek.com>
author:         PageHe  <page_he@realsil.com.cn>
srcversion:     C94095C986767A931B924EF
```

Default is 0 for `msi` so no need for it, but you should for `ips=0 fwlps=0`

Try with both `modprobe` or `insmod`.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your question for how to set parameters, you could use something like (=0 meaning disable, =1 meaning enable, and as Sneetsher mentions msi is disabled by default):

`$ echo "options rtl8723be fwlps=0 ips=0" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf`

Regarding your WiFi problem, you could check out [my answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/632719/my-wifi-drops-the-connection-after-a-few-minutes-realtek8723be/673826#673826) to the question [My wifi drops the connection after a few minutes realtek8723be](https://askubuntu.com/questions/632719/my-wifi-drops-the-connection-after-a-few-minutes-realtek8723be)