# My Wifi drops the connection after a few minutes realtek8723be

Tags: networking, wireless, drivers, realtek-wireless

After install Ubuntu 14.04 LTS ... everything works fine withouth doing update ... after few minutes my wifi drops wireless conn .. I must to reboot for using it again.

My Network controller:

> Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
>   Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be

I used the following script http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=370108

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 06 Jun 2015 12:41 CDT -0500

Booted last: 06 Jun 2015 12:08 CDT -0500

Script from: 21 May 2015 09:10 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

##### kernel ############################

Linux 3.16.0-30-generic #40~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 15 17:43:14 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:b736]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be

09:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:380d]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 045e:0782 Microsoft Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0bda:b728 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 174f:14b8 Syntek 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
2: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

rtl8723be              85054  0 
btcoexist              50304  1 rtl8723be
rtl8723_common         23361  1 rtl8723be
rtl_pci                26690  1 rtl8723be
rtlwifi                64255  2 rtl_pci,rtl8723be
mac80211              652718  3 rtl_pci,rtlwifi,rtl8723be
mxm_wmi                13021  1 nouveau
cfg80211              494330  2 mac80211,rtlwifi
ideapad_laptop         18278  0 
sparse_keymap          13948  1 ideapad_laptop
wmi                    19193  2 mxm_wmi,nouveau

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'eth0' [IF]>  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

vmnet1    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'vmnet1' [IF]>  
          inet addr:172.16.229.1  Bcast:172.16.229.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::250:56ff:fec0:1/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:59 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

vmnet8    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'vmnet8' [IF]>  
          inet addr:192.168.42.1  Bcast:192.168.42.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::250:56ff:fec0:8/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:59 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>  
          inet addr:192.168.1.72  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::2e33:7aff:fe18:82d5/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:25404 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:20720 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:19104265 (19.1 MB)  TX bytes:3957097 (3.9 MB)

##### iwconfig ##########################

eth0      no wireless extensions.

vmnet1    no wireless extensions.

vmnet8    no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"ManzanaVILot176"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: <MAC 'ManzanaVILot176' [AC1]>   
          Bit Rate=18 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=46/70  Signal level=-64 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:57   Missed beacon:0

##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.254   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
172.16.229.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 vmnet1
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     9      0        0 wlan0
192.168.42.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 vmnet8

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.1.1
search gateway.2wire.net

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root       931     1  0 12:08 ?        00:00:00 NetworkManager

##### NetworkManager info ###############

NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: eth0 -----------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            r8169
  State:             unavailable
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        <MAC 'eth0' [IF]>

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         off

- Device: wlan0  [ManzanaVILot176] ---------------------------------------------
  Type:              802.11 WiFi
  Driver:            rtl8723be
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        <MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>

  Capabilities:
    Speed:           18 Mb/s

  Wireless Properties
    WEP Encryption:  yes
    WPA Encryption:  yes
    WPA2 Encryption: yes

  Wireless Access Points (* = current AP)
    INFINITUMc7qc:   Infra, <MAC 'INFINITUMc7qc' [AN1]>, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 100 WPA WPA2
    Zandunga:        Infra, <MAC 'Zandunga' [AN2]>, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 100 WPA2
    *ManzanaVILot176:Infra, <MAC 'ManzanaVILot176' [AC1]>, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 82 WPA
    Motorola:        Infra, <MAC 'Motorola' [AN4]>, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 100 WPA2

  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         192.168.1.72
    Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
    Gateway:         192.168.1.254

    DNS:             192.168.1.254

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/PEMEX MOVIL]] (600 root)
[ipv6] method=auto
[connection] id=PEMEX MOVIL | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=PEMEX MOVIL | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>
[ipv4] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/ManzanaVILot176]] (600 root)
[connection] id=ManzanaVILot176 | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=ManzanaVILot176 | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: America/Mexico_City (based on set time zone)

country US:
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (3, 27)
    (5170 - 5250 @ 40), (3, 17)
    (5250 - 5330 @ 40), (3, 20), DFS
    (5490 - 5600 @ 40), (3, 20), DFS
    (5650 - 5710 @ 40), (3, 20), DFS
    (5735 - 5835 @ 40), (3, 30)
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 40)

##### iwlist channels ###################

eth0      no frequency information.

vmnet1    no frequency information.

vmnet8    no frequency information.

lo        no frequency information.

wlan0     11 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Current Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)

##### iwlist scan #######################

eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

vmnet1    Interface doesn't support scanning.

vmnet8    Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

Channel occupancy:

      1   APs on   Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)

wlan0     Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: <MAC 'ManzanaVILot176' [AC1]>
                    Channel:11
                    Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                    Quality=70/70  Signal level=-32 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"ManzanaVILot176"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                              11 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000001795c479af
                    Extra: Last beacon: 0ms ago
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK

##### module infos ######################

[rtl8723be]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.16.0-30-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtl8723be/rtl8723be.ko
firmware:       rtlwifi/rtl8723befw.bin
description:    Realtek 8723BE 802.11n PCI wireless
license:        GPL
author:         Realtek WlanFAE <wlanfae@realtek.com>
author:         PageHe  <page_he@realsil.com.cn>
srcversion:     C94095C986767A931B924EF
depends:        rtlwifi,rtl8723-common,rtl_pci,btcoexist,mac80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.16.0-30-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        7B:E2:A7:20:0F:17:F0:0C:A0:11:F7:0E:5A:87:4C:37:E3:E0:F6:BE
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           swlps:bool
parm:           swenc:using hardware crypto (default 0 [hardware])
 (bool)
parm:           ips:using no link power save (default 1 is open)
 (bool)
parm:           fwlps:using linked fw control power save (default 1 is open)
 (bool)
parm:           msi:Set to 1 to use MSI interrupts mode (default 0)
 (bool)
parm:           debug:Set debug level (0-5) (default 0) (int)

[rtl8723_common]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.16.0-30-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtl8723com/rtl8723-common.ko
description:    Realtek RTL8723AE/RTL8723BE 802.11n PCI wireless common routines
license:        GPL
author:         Larry Finger    <Larry.Finger@lwfinger.net>
author:         Realtek WlanFAE <wlanfae@realtek.com>
srcversion:     7410431A59C24B1BC33226E
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.16.0-30-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        7B:E2:A7:20:0F:17:F0:0C:A0:11:F7:0E:5A:87:4C:37:E3:E0:F6:BE
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

[rtl_pci]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.16.0-30-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtl_pci.ko
description:    PCI basic driver for rtlwifi
license:        GPL
author:         Larry Finger    <Larry.FInger@lwfinger.net>
author:         Realtek WlanFAE <wlanfae@realtek.com>
author:         lizhaoming  <chaoming_li@realsil.com.cn>
srcversion:     3273ECD6028617EFD27E4F4
depends:        mac80211,rtlwifi
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.16.0-30-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        7B:E2:A7:20:0F:17:F0:0C:A0:11:F7:0E:5A:87:4C:37:E3:E0:F6:BE
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

[rtlwifi]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.16.0-30-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtlwifi.ko
description:    Realtek 802.11n PCI wireless core
license:        GPL
author:         Larry Finger    <Larry.FInger@lwfinger.net>
author:         Realtek WlanFAE <wlanfae@realtek.com>
author:         lizhaoming  <chaoming_li@realsil.com.cn>
srcversion:     8362106E96F806A9DBAE565
depends:        mac80211,cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.16.0-30-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        7B:E2:A7:20:0F:17:F0:0C:A0:11:F7:0E:5A:87:4C:37:E3:E0:F6:BE
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.16.0-30-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
srcversion:     D421794D4F30DF3A540FD24
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.16.0-30-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        7B:E2:A7:20:0F:17:F0:0C:A0:11:F7:0E:5A:87:4C:37:E3:E0:F6:BE
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.16.0-30-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     DEE8EAA48495E392CD51C2D
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.16.0-30-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        7B:E2:A7:20:0F:17:F0:0C:A0:11:F7:0E:5A:87:4C:37:E3:E0:F6:BE
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[rtl8723be]
debug: 0
fwlps: Y
ips: Y
msi: N
swenc: N
swlps: N

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
probe_wait_ms: 500

[cfg80211]
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

lp
rtc

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

[/etc/modprobe.d/modesetting.conf]
options cirrus modeset=1
options mgag200 modeset=1

[/etc/modprobe.d/vmware-fuse.conf]
alias char-major-10-229 fuse

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

[/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules]
# PCI device 0x10ec:0x8168 (r8169)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC 'eth0' [IF]>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"
# PCI device 0x10ec:0xb723 (rtl8723be)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"

##### dmesg #############################

[   14.797584] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[   17.537314] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC 'ManzanaVILot176' [AC1]>
[   17.557419] wlan0: send auth to <MAC 'ManzanaVILot176' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[   17.559066] wlan0: authenticated
[   17.559222] rtl8723be 0000:08:00.0 wlan0: disabling HT/VHT due to WEP/TKIP use
[   17.559226] rtl8723be 0000:08:00.0 wlan0: disabling HT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
[   17.559228] rtl8723be 0000:08:00.0 wlan0: disabling VHT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
[   17.561054] wlan0: associate with <MAC 'ManzanaVILot176' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[   17.565123] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC 'ManzanaVILot176' [AC1]> (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=2)
[   17.565270] wlan0: associated
[   17.565277] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
[   17.630615] bridge-wlan0: device is wireless, enabling SMAC
[   17.630617] bridge-wlan0: up
[   17.630619] bridge-wlan0: attached
[   17.630912] wlan0: deauthenticating from <MAC 'ManzanaVILot176' [AC1]> by local choice (Reason: 2=PREV_AUTH_NOT_VALID)
[   17.663519] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC 'ManzanaVILot176' [AC1]>
[   17.673669] wlan0: send auth to <MAC 'ManzanaVILot176' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[   17.673891] bridge-wlan0: disabling the bridge
[   17.675828] wlan0: authenticated
[   17.675922] rtl8723be 0000:08:00.0 wlan0: disabling HT/VHT due to WEP/TKIP use
[   17.675924] rtl8723be 0000:08:00.0 wlan0: disabling HT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
[   17.675926] rtl8723be 0000:08:00.0 wlan0: disabling VHT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
[   17.677178] wlan0: associate with <MAC 'ManzanaVILot176' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[   17.679555] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC 'ManzanaVILot176' [AC1]> (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=2)
[   17.679703] wlan0: associated
[   17.689281] bridge-wlan0: down
[   17.689287] bridge-wlan0: detached
[   17.755541] bridge-wlan0: device is wireless, enabling SMAC
[   17.755543] bridge-wlan0: up
[   17.755546] bridge-wlan0: attached

########## wireless info END ############
```

Comment: No one can help you if that's all the detail you give. PC maker, model, wifi card maker? One shot: bad router config, try assigning a static IP to your machine from said router config.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output if `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: FYI, here is a bug report for it: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1461174

Comment: Did you find any answer to the above problem. I am facing the similar issue. My laptop has also got the same rtl8723be .

Comment: You can try my method but only applicable for rtl8723be drivers.
[Click here](https://learntillyoudie.wordpress.com/2016/07/06/wifi-issue-in-laptops-having-rtl8732be-drivers/) for the solution. Hope it helped you :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Realtek 8723BE Wifi problem](http://askubuntu.com/questions/635625/realtek-8723be-wifi-problem)

Answer (score 10):

After lots of Googling, I found a [recent post](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1454843/comments/7) with new firmware.

1. Download [rtl8723befw.bin](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1454843/+attachment/4438588/+files/rtl8723befw.bin), copy it to **/lib/firmware/rtlwifi/** and then reboot your laptop.
2. Disable the sleep feature of the driver:

   `$ echo "options rtl8723be fwlps=0" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf`

   (I also found information using `options rtl8723be fwlps=N ips=N`, which disables the `ips` option, but I did not find it necessary to use this)

I also read in many posts that bluetooth can disrupt the WiFi connection, so I permanently disabled it also:
 
`$ sudo rfkill block bluetooth
$ sudo update-rc.d bluetooth disable`

(and check it's turned off with `sudo service bluetooth status`)

[If you find you are still having problems with WiFi suddenly breaking, you can reload the relevant module with `sudo rmmod rtl8723be && sudo modprobe rtl8723be`, instead of having to reboot your whole system]

Comment: Having used my laptop for the majority of today, I have had no WiFi failures requiring a reboot or reloading of the module. I did have one or two periods where my WiFi was not particularly fast, but it looks as though they have [found the issue and are working on it](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1454843/comments/9)

Answer (score 3):

Having spent a lot of time on multiple forums when I hit this issue on **Lenovo G40** and **HP Notebook 15-ac122tu**, I found this was a pretty common problem with WiFi not working or stoped working intermittently on Ubuntu 14.04.

To me, following three links were relevant:

1) [How do I get a Realtek RTL8723BE wireless card to work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/635625/realtek-8723be-wifi-problem)

2) [Wifi problems with rtl8723be in Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/590414/wifi-problems-with-rtl8723be-in-ubuntu-14-04)

3) [My Wifi drops the connection after a few minutes realtek8723be](https://askubuntu.com/questions/632719/my-wifi-drops-the-connection-after-a-few-minutes-realtek8723be) (this post)

What worked for me is a mix of these three posts and some troubleshooting.

I think, a permanent fix in Ubuntu mainline packages with respect to Broadcom or Realtek WiFi adapters will help users. This will go a long way to make Ubuntu more user friendly. Remember, there was time when audio and graphics issues were pretty common, recently it is the same with wireless adapters.