# Internet access lost after a minute

Tags: wireless, internet

I installed ubuntu 14.04 on my notebook. I **can't access internet** even when i am connected to wifi. No matter how many restarts, no matter how many connections-disconnections to the network the internet access **dissapears after a short period of time**.

With **cable works fine**, so I am guessing it has something to do with wifi.

ps: I have also installed Windows and everything works great!

lspci -knn | grep Net -A2

```
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]
    Subsystem: XAVi Technologies Corp. Device [1b9a:2485]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be
```

Comment: Try disabling ipv6. If you are still having a problem you need to identify your hardware. In general, it is easiest to purchase linux compatible wireless cards which can be 10 or less

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen Disabling ipv6 didnt work!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wifi problems with rtl8723be in Ubuntu 14.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/590414/wifi-problems-with-rtl8723be-in-ubuntu-14-04)

Comment: Please [run the WiFi diagnostics](/a/425205/175814) and [edit] your question to include a link to the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I googled "RTL8732BE linux driver" which gave me [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/590414/wifi-problems-with-rtl8723be-in-ubuntu-14-04) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/632719/my-wifi-drops-the-connection-after-a-few-minutes-realtek8723be), both which looks like exactly your problem.

You'll need to install a proper driver for your wifi adapter. There are answers in both threads that show you how.

Comment: I hope if installing a new driver for my wifi adapter wont affect wifi-connection on Windows! Thanks for your effort!

Comment: You need to install it on Ubuntu, so that will not affect your Windows installation.

Comment: I took courage and followed the first thread. It work! Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

This is based on the Trial with the rtl8732be.conf file located in /etc/modprobe.d/ folder

Create or Edit the existing file by typing the below code in terminal

```
 sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf
```

Type your root password then copy and paste below given text

```
options rtl8723be fwlps=N ips=N ant_sel=1
```

Save the file & Reboot.
Now you should have a proper working WIFI.

Hope This helps all of you, This worked on my new HP245 G5 laptop with 16.04.1

Thanks to all who have tried to post information to get this wifi device working.