# Ubuntu 18.04 : Internet keeps going on and off while wifi is connected

Tags: 16.04, 18.04

I am using **Ubuntu 18.04** and my internet remains on for some time and then goes off (so basically ping doesn't work and neither does any website load inside the browser). I have to reconnect to the wifi and continue. I am not facing any such issues in Windows 10/my mobile using the same wifi network.

Note : This problem occurred in ubuntu **16.04** LTS as well hence I upgraded to 18.04 , it worked fine for 2 days and then again the problem started occurring. Also, I tried editing /etc/resolv.conf to have **nameserver 8.8.8.8** but no effect. Also tried to decipher something from output of :

> journalctl /usr/sbin/NetworkManager

but couldnt understand much what is exactly failing. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Edit** : 
1. Output of

> sudo lshw -class network | grep driver

is here :  https://pastebin.com/as5gU5te

2. Output of

   > sudo modinfo $DRIVER

is here : https://pastebin.com/YJeuQxtP  and I see **fwlps:Set to 1 to use FW control power save (default 1)** in the output.

3. I currently cannot see any relevant output from

   > journalctl -k

hence will update it with  relevant content when error occurs.

Also,if it is due to wifi dongle issue, it doesn't occur when I'm using windows 10, so I think that might not be the issue although I am not exactly sure.

Comment: Upload the content to pastebin.com if you think it might be relevant and then others can analyse it. There are a lot of things that it might be, I'd try looking at `dmesg` when the error occurs (or `journalctl -k`). My first guess would be power saving on your wifi dongle/card/chip (if when it goes down wifi is accessible from other devices). `sudo lshw -class network | grep driver` will tell you your driver, and `sudo modinfo $DRIVER` will give info about it including for example if it has powersave.

Comment: Thanks @pbhj for looking into the issue. I've edited the question with relevant info on pastebin.

Comment: So now you can [set options](https://askubuntu.com/questions/526214/how-to-set-parameters-for-realtek-wifi-rtl8723) and see if it works. You could look at Windows devicemanager to find how the options are set there. (There are other things this could be, if the dropouts are regular, and don't affect other devices on the same router/AP, then this to be is most likely.) Backup your /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf before you change it. Also, there may be hidden options, so google it!